# Django next parameter not working in production

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a django app. In my local server, when i try to access http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/cursos/verredacaoforum/31, for example, it works (goes to /cursos/verredacaoforum/31).

But in production, it seems that "next" parameter is not recognized, and it makes a normal login.

The login code is exactly the same.
In production (digital ocean), i'm using gunicorn and nginx.

Is there any different setting in prouction that could be causing this bug? It's my first django app in production mode.

I really appreciate any help.

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: If i were to guess, your nginx rules might be losing the get query parameters.

Comment: It's possible. I will check it tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The solution was to add "django.core.context_processors.request" to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS (it is not there by default)  in my settings file.